# Display data from database to specific users (using roles?)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, user-roles

I want to display some data to specific users. I've already done something similar but the difference is that the role number was static. For example I added a column and gave '1' to specific users, so I wrote if($role == 1) { do something }. That was fine because it's a static number. With this way I'm showing secret information only to users with role 1.

Now I've added a new feature; the admin can upload information for specific users that belong to a group. Info will be different for groups. The data is stored and retrieved just fine. That's not my problem. For example I want to display document A to users 'a1','a2','a3' who are in group A (it's random names, i just want to make it easier for you), document B to users 'a4','a7','a35','a40' (who are in group B) and so on.

I know how to store/retrieve document 'A' and link it with users 'a1','a2','a3' and their group... but I'm not sure how I can show each document to a group. Document A can only be linked with one group (same for B,C,D.. etc).

```
TABLES
DOCUMENTS
Number - Title - File
1 - Document A - A.doc
2 - Document B - B.doc

DOC_USERS
Doc N - User N
1 - 10
1 - 15
2 - 7

DOC_GROUPS
Doc N - Group N
1 - 1
2 - 2
```

Instead of saying if($role == 1) as I did before.. I will need something like if ($document == $group).
I cannot put 'A', or 'B' or whatever because it's not static though.

Any help?

Comment: Can we see how your tables are setup?

Comment: Hard to understand what the question is without code. Without code, you are asking for suggestions, which is not a good fit for SO

Comment: I've just added a table.

Comment: I haven't added any code Juan because it works fine. I know how to retrieve the values (group id, assignment id, users id). I just don't understand how I can compare them and restrict information to specific users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move this logic into the query rather than the view.  Pass in the user_id as a parameter and return only the records that the user is allowed to view.  It looks like your schema allows you to grant permission to a document based on your userID, or by a user's association with a group (which seems to be missing from the table structure, but you mentioned it in your description)

```
select documents.*
from documents
     inner join doc_users on documents.number= doc_users.doc
where doc_users.user = ?

Union

select documents.*
from documents
     inner join doc_groups on documents.number= doc_group.doc
     inner join user_groups on user_groups.group = doc_groups.group
where user_groups.user = ?
```

i'm sure this query could be done without a union, but this is pretty clear to read and understand.

Comment: that make more sense! A really simple way, don't know why I was trying to do it by using roles lol. Thanks a lot